# flutter pop back without dismissing keyboard in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart

I want to implement something like this

[image: whatsapp swipe on ios]

But i get something like this

[image: linked in swipe]

this is what i tried

[image: this is what i get]

is there any way to not dismiss the keyboard when navigating back? I mean i want to dismiss the keyboard but i want it like the first video which implemented on whatsapp

### **main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const MyHomePage(
              title: 'home',
            ),
        '/nextpage': (context) => const NextPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

---

### **page.dart**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/nextpage');
      }),
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NextPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<NextPage> createState() => _NextPageState();
}

class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('next page'),
      ),
      body: const SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.maxFinite,
        child: Center(
          child: TextField(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the code that I did to replicate this. Its default behavior is like that but I wonder if we can change the behavior such as the video using flutter.

Comment: Kindly share your tried code.

Comment: @HarshSureja already provided the minimal code you can replicate

Comment: @Vaidarbhi yup thats right but i dont want it to occur showing the animation of the keyboard going down.. it just stay up with the screen but gone for the current screen after pop.. exactly just like the video.